# Sails.js - Querying array size

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

```
// Item.js
schema: true,
attributes: {
    testArray: {
        type: 'array',
        required: true,
        array: true
    }
}
```

I would like to find all items where the `testArray` attribute have a specific length.

I tried with this code below, but it doesn't work.

```
Item.find({testArray: {length: 2}}).exec(function (err, items) {
    console.log(items);
});
```

I also tried with `minLength`, `maxLength`, `size`, but still no results.
Is there is a way to do that?

I'm using **MongoDB** via [Sails.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails)/[Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline).

Comment: What kind of database are you using? For this operation you need to make a call to the underlaying db layer.

Comment: @artworkadシ I'm using MongoDB, I have updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is in documentation

```
Model.where({ property: { '>': 100 }})
```

http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models

Another solution:

```
var query = { testArray: { $size: { $gt:2 } } };

Item.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.find(query).toArray(function(err, items) {
        //items contains objects where testArray.length is greater than 2
    });
});
```

You might run into problems depending on your mongodb version, then read http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-find-all-documents-where-an-array-list-size-is-greater-than-n/